# gulp.series() assertion error with Gulp v4

Tags: gulp

Am I doing something wrong or is this a gulp v4 problem? When running the "build-minify" task, I get the following error:

```
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/mnt/d/BriteTank 1d/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/mnt/d/BriteTank 1d/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/BriteTank 1d/gulpfile.js:60:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

As best as I can tell, I've written everything the way gulp v4 expects ([Gulp 4 New Task Execution System](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/)). This code worked with gulp v3.9.1 with the "build-minify" task written this way:

```
gulp.task("build-minify", ["sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version"]);
```

Here's the new code, that throws an error:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
let cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task('sass-by-version', function () {
 return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(stylesheetsDest));
});

gulp.task('minify-css-by-version', () => {
    return gulp.src(stylesheetsSrc + ".css")
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(file => file.base));
});

gulp.task("build-minify", gulp.series("sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting an error. I used your script in my environment (`"gulp": "^4.0.0"` and `"gulp-clean-css": "^3.10.0"`) and it worked as soon as I added `stylesheetsSrc` as well as `stylesheetsDest`. Did your `gulpfile.js` include these two variables?

Note that I changed `return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')` to a path that reflected mine which was `return gulp.src('./resources/assets/**/*.scss')` but this shouldn't have an impact on your build.

See my code below which includes `stylesheetsSrc` and `stylesheetsDest`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
let cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var stylesheetsDest = './tests/';
var stylesheetsSrc = './public/css/app';

gulp.task('sass-by-version', function () {
 return gulp.src('./resources/assets/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(stylesheetsDest));
});

gulp.task('minify-css-by-version', () => {
    return gulp.src(stylesheetsSrc + ".css")
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(file => file.base));
});

gulp.task(
    "build-minify",
    gulp.series("sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version")
);
```

And here is the console output:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev /Volumes/500GB/master
> gulp build-minify

[00:05:12] Using gulpfile /Volumes/500GB/master/gulpfile.js
[00:05:12] Starting 'build-minify'...
[00:05:12] Starting 'sass-by-version'...
[00:05:13] Finished 'sass-by-version' after 677 ms
[00:05:13] Starting 'minify-css-by-version'...
[00:05:13] Finished 'minify-css-by-version' after 879 ms
[00:05:13] Finished 'build-minify' after 1.56 s
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just seeing your answer now! I believe what happened is that I thought I was using Gulp 4, but I don't think I used "@latest" when installing it though npm, so I was actually still using the older Gulp. So you were right, it was working code, given the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine, just delete `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` and do `npm install` and then run the build again it will work.

If you want to understand the migration of tasks from Gulp 3 to Gulp 4 :

Old Code:

`gulp.task("build-minify", ["sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version"]);`

New Code:

- If you want to run the task one by one:

  `gulp.task("build-minify", gulp.series("sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version"]));`
- If you want to run the task in parallel:

  `gulp.task("build-minify", gulp.parallel("sass-by-version", "minify-css-by-version"]));`